# Passing id in salesforce trigger?

Tags: trigger

I have trigger with a some logic over here and in logic if condition is false then it send an emails to the queue members for that i created a queue in salesforce but how that queue id value is pass in the below code.

this is my trigger logic

```
  List<Case> cases = Trigger.new;
         List<Case_User__c> availableCaseUsers = [SELECT AvailableUsers__c, Timings__c, SkillSet__c FROM Case_User__c where Availability__c = TRUE ORDER BY Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c ASC];
         //List<Case_User__c> availableCaseUsers = Database.query(queryString);
         integer i=0;
         integer nomatchingSkillset = availableCaseUsers.size();
         for(Case c: cases){
             for(; i<=availableCaseUsers.size();i++){
                if(availableCaseUsers.get(i).SkillSet__c.contains(c.CaseRelatedTo__c)){
                  c.OwnerId = availableCaseUsers.get(i).AvailableUsers__c;
                  availableCaseUsers.get(i).Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c = DateTime.now();
                  cusermap.put(availableCaseUsers.get(i).id, availableCaseUsers.get(i));
                } else {
                      nomatchingSkillset--;
                      if(nomatchingSkillset == 0){

                          how to assign to case queue

                          break;
                      }
                      continue; 
                }
                if(i>=availableCaseUsers.size()){
                    i=0;
                }
                break;
             }      
         }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate...http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165513/assigining-the-id-in-trigger

Answer (score 1):

You the below query to get the user's email address for a queue

```
SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN (
       SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.DeveloperName ='aaa');
```

Once you have these details, everything is pretty easy

Comment: thanks for replying Doe here Group.DeveloperName ='aaa' is this is member name?

Comment: Queue name use queue name here

Comment: Doe i pass the queue name but i didn't get the emails when criteria meet

Comment: First run the query on developer console to make sure that you are getting user's email. It is working for me .

Comment: yes in console i get the email id that;s fine but this query is added in the above else condition and created a new case but no member get the emails  please help to resolve